# Storyboard.SetTargetProperty not working under Windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following extension method that I am using from a [gesture example app I found online](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/06/06/a-gesture-driven-windows-phone-to-do-application.html) for Windows Phone 7. I am trying to migrate it to 8.1 for my app, but have run in to problems with the `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty` method invocation. It appears that [this signature is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25424850/1815321) in Windows 8.1.

I am fairly new to Windows Phone development in general and not sure what I should use in place of this, can someone point me to a method in the API that provides what this is trying to achieve? It appears that the signature now requires a string, where previously a PropertyPath was allowed. I'm not sure what I need to do to transform a DP property into a string that represents it, will a string set to the name of the DP property work?

```
public static void Animate(this DependencyObject target, double from, double to,
                        object propertyPath, int duration, int startTime,
                        Action completed = null)
{
    var db = new DoubleAnimation();
    db.To = to;
    db.From = from;
    db.EasingFunction = new SineEase();
    db.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(db, target);

    // Compiler error: This method signature is no longer supported.
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(db, new PropertyPath(propertyPath));

    var sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startTime);

    if (completed != null)
    {
        sb.Completed += (s, e) => completed();
    }

    sb.Children.Add(db);
    sb.Begin();
}
```

**Invoked like this**

```
TranslateTransform elementTrans = new TranslateTransform();
elementTrans.Animate(0, elementOffset, TranslateTransform.YProperty, 200, startTime, null, action);
```

Not sure how to transform the `TranslateTransform.YProperty` in to a string that can be passed in to the `SetTargetProperty` call.

**Edit**

I [have found some documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.settargetproperty.aspx) that shows how to pass the property name in via a string. I don't think that I am providing it correctly though as I get a runtime exception that it can't find the property provided.

```
        transform.Animate(transform.X, 0, "(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.XProperty)", 300, 0, new BounceEase()
        {
            Bounciness = 5,
            Bounces = 2
        });
```

Note that I changed the method signature to accept a string for `propertyPath` instead of an object, but did not reflect that here as I wanted to keep the original source above as-is from my original post.

The `RenderTransform` is set to a `TranslateTransform` like this:

```
    public static void SetHorizontalOffset(this FrameworkElement element, double offset)
    {
        var transform = new TranslateTransform { X = offset };
        element.RenderTransform = transform;
        element.Tag = new Offset { Value = offset, Transform = transform };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the full property path. Simply have `X` instead of the whole `(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.XProperty)`.

e.g.

```
transform.Animate(transform.X, 0, "X", 300, 0, new BounceEase()
{
    Bounciness = 5,
    Bounces = 2
});
```

Comment: No worries, also to note, `TranslateTransform.X` would work too. :)